# set only parent ul padding to 0

Tags: css

In chrome (and possible in other explorers) the ul element has a default padding that gives it a nice deeper indent to each depth level of the ul.

i.e. the first `ul` will get padding of `10px`, the second `ul>ul` will get `20px` and so on.

I've tried to find a way to make only the first one with padding 0 so that it'll get a nice position for him without damaging the child uls indention structure.
And that's the result:

Answer (score 0):

This code will make all ul elements that are not direct children of a li element with padding 0 (or whatever code you'd like to put there).

```
*:not(li) > ul {
  padding: 0;
  /* more code */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution, if you don't need to support IE8 and below is this:

```
:not(ul) ul {
    padding-left:0;
}
```

If you actually need to support some legacy browsers, you'll have to specify a general padding for `ul` elements yourself:

```
ul {
    padding-left:0;
}
ul ul {
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough but you did just the opposite of what I tried to do. I tired  to make only the first ul to  be with no padding - i.e. all children uls (all uls except for the highest parent) will be  default. You disabled the defaults for all child uls and made padding for the parent ul.

Comment: Sorry, you were clear enough, I didn't read correctly, I fixed my answer. Now I saw you already answered your own question...that's weird.